# Satisfying Chrome deprecation of # in url but breaking svg mask

Tags: javascript, svg

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
>
  <!-- MASK DEFINITION -->
  
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#fff"/>

      <rect class="rect"
            x="10"
            y="10"
            width="20"
            height="20"
      >
      </rect>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <!-- MASK DEF -->

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" mask="url(%23mask)"/>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
>
  <!-- MASK DEFINITION -->
  
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#fff"/>

      <rect class="rect"
            x="10"
            y="10"
            width="20"
            height="20"
      >
      </rect>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <!-- MASK DEF -->

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

I have an svg with a mask. Another element uses the mask as such:

```
mask="url(#mask)"
```

While trying to satisfy this: [Treat '#' as ending data URI body content](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720)
I changed my svg mask to "url(%23mask)", but that totally breaks the mask.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue? Is there a way to satisfy both chrome and the mask?

Code snippet below contains two identical svg's; the only difference is that one uses a # and the other uses %23 when defining their urls.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added code snippet

Comment: you can only use %23 if you're encoding a data URL, that's not the case here.